# Accessing boolean values from application.conf in a scala template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a boolean parameter in application.conf:

```
system.debugMode = false
```

And I'm trying to branch based on the value of this in my scala template:

```
<p>Debug mode parameter value: @Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("system.debugMode")</p>

@if(Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("system.debugMode")) {
    <p>Debug mode on</p>
} else {
    <p>Debug mode off</p>
}
```

I would expect to see the output 'debug mode off', but what I actually see rendered  is:

```
Debug mode parameter value: false

Debug mode on
```

Do I have a casting issue here? It seems my value is coming back from the config file as 'false' but the @if statement is evaluating it as true. I note that the API states that the getBoolean method returns an option containing a boolean, so maybe this can't be put into an if evaluation?

Comment: An option isn't a boolean. To get the result you want, you will need to determine if the option contains a boolean and decide how to act if it does, and if it doesn't. eg.: `@if(Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("system.debugMode").getOrElse(true)) {` - this example assumes a value of true unless specifically set. Change to `getOrElse(false)` if you want to assume false unless set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`play.api.Configuration.getBoolean()` returns an `Option[Boolean]`. In Play's template engine, an `Option` containing `Some(...)` will always evaluate to true in an if conditional, even if the option contains `Some(false)`.

As a test, I've created all possible values for an `Option[Boolean]` and tested what happened with them inside an `@if(...)` in a template.

**Controller:**

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    val a: Option[Boolean] = None
    val b: Option[Boolean] = Some(true)
    val c: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)
    Ok(views.html.index(a, b, c))
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
@(a: Option[Boolean], b: Option[Boolean], c: Option[Boolean])

@if(a) { a }
@if(b) { b }
@if(c) { c }
```

Running it gives the output *"b c"*.

If your config parameter has a default value, get the Option's value with `getOrElse`:

```
Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("system.debugMode").getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

If you're sure that the config parameter will always be there (or you're happy with your template reporting that debug mode is off if the parameter is not set), you can also `flatten` the option:

```
Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("system.debugMode").flatten
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the syntax I needed.